# variable length stream records with python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, telnetlib

I am using [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) to telnet my device.
the device return variable length records priodically with NO delimeter.

every record has a date and time in the begining of itself, which I can use as a delimeter.

How can I use [Telnet.expect(list[, timeout])](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect) to separate records.

Example Stream:

```
10/20/12_17:58:24 TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT ..........
                  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT ..........
                  TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........
                  TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........

10/20/12_17:58:28  TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........
     TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT .......... TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT .......... TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..

10/20/12_17:58:34  TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........
                 TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........
                 TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........

10/20/12_17:59:25  TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........
      TEXT TEXT TEXTTEXT ..........
```

Comment: I think the "block quoting" or indentation of your sample needs a few tweaks.  The lines of all asterisks are being interpreted as horizontal rules.

Comment: "block qouting" tweaked,  I need records with their Date and Time (first row in any record)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that each line starts with white-space, if it is not a first line of the record.

If that is correct, then use regex pattern `^(?!\s)` or `[\n\r](?!\s)` as a delimeter.

If that is not correct, then as a delimiter use regex pattern `^(?=\d+\/\d+\/\d+_\d+:\d+:\d+\s)` or `[\n\r](?=\d+\/\d+\/\d+_\d+:\d+:\d+\s)`